# isotope - 'no results' message?

Tags: jquery-isotope

I'm using the Isotope JS plugin (v2.0.1) from Metafizzy to filter a library of publications, and I am using more than one filter (e.g. publisher and industry). Is there a way to check if my combination of filters has resulted in zero results, and then show a corresponding message... something like "Sorry. No matching items found."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$container.isotope({ filter: '.your-filter' });

  if ( !$container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms.length ) {
    $('.message-div').fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    $('.message-div').fadeOut('fast');
  }
```

You could also use hide/show or a number of other effects instead of fadeIn and fadeOut depending on your effect.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, in the version of Isotope I am using (v2.1.1) I actually had to do it with `filterItems.length` so it was: `if ( !$('.izotope-container').data('isotope').filteredItems.length ) {`

Comment: You can also achieve the same using the 'arrangeCompleted' event.  That event provides two parameters to the function: event and filteredItems.  filteredItems will give you the number of items after applying the filter and finished all the animations.  I think this is more accurate. `$grid.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
  if( filteredItems.length > 0 ) // hide message else // show message;
});`

Comment: This worked for me:

`var elems = $grid.isotope('getFilteredItemElements');
if ( !elems.length ) {
$('.project__filter--msg').show();
} else {
$('.project__filter--msg').hide();
}`